# In SQL - Grabbing the counts of multiple tables; and then inserting counts + string into a new table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write a PL/SQL script to collect the counts  of about 30 tables, and then to insert those counts into a new table(which would have thirty rows). So the new table might look like:

```
CS_ADM_CV    27
CS_CV_IBM    38
CS_CV_ORA    99
CS_YY_CIS    12
```

...ETC

How do I go about doing this? This is what I have so far, it's not working like I want to.

```
    SELECT  (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            from   STGADM.CI_ACCT
            ) AS 'STGADM.CI_ACCT',
/*  More like this etc etc */
            (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            from   STGADM.CI_TNDR_CTL
            ) as 'STGADM.CI_TNDR_CTL'

    from    DUAL
    into STGADM-CCBMIG.CV_PLSQL_COUNT;
```

It looks like I have the wrong idea about how to get all the counts and then insert them into a new table(I left out the trivial `CREATE` statements).

Someone tells me to use PL/SQL VAR's to do this. onot sure

The full code - http://pastebin.com/48ExZWq0

I need any tip/help , thanks

Comment: Why are you saving off this data?  What plan do you have?  You current format is getting 30 columns, essentially, but you want rows (so, you could combine the queries with `UNION`).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - Hmm, I'm trying to understand how the current one is "30 columns" vs rows. let me think a sec. thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you can't use the `num_rows` from `dba_tables` which would be the possibly approximated counts from the point in time that statistics were gathered rather than the current counts, the most simplistic approach would be

```
SELECT 'CS_ADM_CV' table_name,
       COUNT(*) cnt
  FROM STGADM.CS_ADM_CV
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CS_CV_IBM' table_name,
       COUNT(*) cnt
  FROM STGADM.CS_CV_IBM
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CS_CV_ORA' table_name,
       COUNT(*) cnt
  FROM STGADM.CS_CV_ORA
...
```

It is also possible to write a [single query that returns the number of rows in every table in a particular schema](http://laurentschneider.com/wordpress/2007/04/how-do-i-store-the-counts-of-all-tables.html) but that gets into some pretty sophisticated XML query topics.  Unless you need the flexibility of getting a different set of rows when a new table is added, listing out 30 tables is likely to be the easier solution.